# Spring JDBC appearing to randomly rollback transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I was checking database consistencies during my web application testing and I discovered a strange occurrence.

There is a gap of Id's in every table between certain times. ie, Every ID between 114 and 130 has gone, with approximately 20 minutes separating them.

To elaborate, it has the appearance of a rolled back transaction; there are no records of the rows, no triggers have been executed, and no logs have been recorded.

There is nothing in my application that could remove data from any table, so I'm left to believe that spring rolled back a large transaction (of multiple database requests) that it had left uncommitted.

The autocommit option is on, and the server was not restarted in this time period.

Has anyone heard of anything like this happening before? Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated...

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Looking in Tomcat logs it appears that the server forced a restart around the right time.
Would this cause JDBC to rollback a transaction like this?

The server seems to have restarted without reason... Is this a bug with Tomcat or JDBC?

Comment: For one thing, having autocommit turned on sounds like a bad idea. But if you have autocommit on, how can you have a large transaction to get rolled back?

Comment: Good question, I have no idea. Can anyone elaborate on how Spring JDBC handles transactions?

Comment: I think the assumption that it was a single large transaction might be wrong. Given the restart, it was probably a single transaction that was attempted many times. Whatever was causing the transaction to rollback was probably leaking memory or doing something else that eventually caused the restart.

Comment: Possibly. I've been checking the database activity monitor, and it looks as if Spring opens a transaction to the database, which sleeps when not actually in use.
Killing this transaction doesn't seem to cause the rollback I've seen though. And Spring reopens the transaction on the next database request.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't restart without a reason, something caused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's generally agreed that the ungraceful shutdown of Tomcat is what caused the rollback.

I have started to use a different implementation of Springs transaction manager, which will hopefully not cause the problem to occur again.

Thanks.